# Assembly code not working with nasm

Tags: assembly, nasm, 32-bit, cls-compliant

i am learning assembly as part of my course. This code is to clear screen and then type 4529. It is quite old-school style, though our teacher explains things very well so i will stick with this style of code instead of using HLA or macros etc.. Now coming to the problem. Even if i copy-paste the exact code into a .asm and compile it with nasm -o directive as instructed, the program does nothing. If i run it within dosbox, it clears screen but fails to print the number. is the code so ancient that my 32-bit OS will not support it no matter what? please help - i need to learn this coding-style for a: to pass the course ,  b: the lecture handouts are quite good otherwise and i hesitate from buying a large book on ASM.

```
       [org 0x0100]
jmp start  
   clr:     mov ax, 0xb800
            mov es, ax
            mov di, 0

   nxt:     mov word[es:di], 0x0720
            add di,2
            cmp di,4000
            jnz nxt
            ret

prntnum:    push bp
            mov bp, sp
            push es
            push ax
            push bx
            push cx
            push dx
            push di


            mov ax, 0x0b800
            mov es,ax
            mov ax,[bp+4]
            mov bx, 10  
            mov cx, 0



nxtdigit:       mov dx,0
            div bx
            add dl,0x30
            push dx
            inc cx
            cmp ax,0
            jnz nxtdigit

            mov di,0

nextpos:            pop dx
            mov dh,0x07
            mov [es:di],dx
            add di,2
            loop nextpos

            pop di
            pop dx
            pop cx
            pop bx
            pop ax
            pop es
            pop bp
            ret 2




start:      call clr
            mov ax, 4529
            push ax         
            call prntnum

            mov ax,0x4c00
            int 0x21
```

Comment: Did your instructor not recommend a development environment?

Comment: (distance-learning archived videos:)Simply write the code in any text editor, compile with nasm and debug with afd. I couldnt find a manual on afd either. Currently, this is more like pre-semester work so i cannot ask peers either

Comment: Code looks fine, FWIW, so it must have something to do either with the way you're building the COM file or the environment you run it in. It assumes that it can write to the VGA adapter's video memory at 0xB800, which is certainly a valid assumptions on most real DOS boxes, but I don't know if that always holds in a (virtual) DOS box.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved - - it seems i was writing itusing black color attribute and so no text was visible. Once that got changed, all programs are runnign fine.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using 16 bit code in NASM, you may need to tell nasm the code is 16 bit with the syntax

```
[16 bit]
```

at the start